# RecyclerView freezing with Glide

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-glide, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I am using glide in a cursor adapter to load thousands of views. They all have a small image attached to them loaded from disk (all less than 10kb). However i am getting freezing and the issue seems to come from the Glide library (however it might be due to the cursorloader). I attached my code and log files below.

Relevant CursorAdapter Code:

```
public FilesFragmentCursorAdapter(Activity context, Cursor cursor, Bucket bucket) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        mContext = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        mBucket = bucket;
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        downloader = new ThumbnailDownloader(mContext, mBucket);
        manager = GlideApp.with(mContext);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mShowThumbnails = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(Constants.PREFS_SHOW_THUMBNAILS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_file_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        FileViewHolder holder = new FileViewHolder();

        holder.mId = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_id);
        holder.mName = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_name);
        holder.mSize = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_size);
        holder.mCreated = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_date);
        holder.image = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_image);
        holder.container = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_item);

        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
        long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SIZE));
        String created = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT));
        String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MIME));

        if (id != null) holder.mId.setText(id);
        if (name != null) holder.mName.setText(name);
        String fileSize = Formatter.formatFileSize(mContext, size);
        holder.mSize.setText(fileSize);
        if (created != null && created.length() > 10) {
            String fileCreatedDate = created.substring(0, 10);
            holder.mCreated.setText(fileCreatedDate);
        }
        if (mimeType != null) {
            if (mimeType.contains("image")) {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_black_48dp);
                if (mShowThumbnails) {
                    String thumbnailPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL));
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(thumbnailPath)) {
                        manager.load(thumbnailPath).skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(holder.image);
                    } else {
                        File current = DatabaseHelper.createFileFromCursor(cursor);
                        downloader.download(current);
                    }
                }
            } else if (mimeType.contains("video")) {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_videocam_black_48dp);
            } else if (mimeType.contains("text")) {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_text_format_black_48dp);
            } else if (mimeType.contains("audio")) {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_black_48dp);
            } else {
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
12-28 21:47:17.212 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/Parcel: fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC) failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 1, error: Too many open files
12-28 21:47:20.150 27355-27752/co.intellidev.storj E/libEGL: error creating cache file /data/user_de/0/co.intellidev.storj/code_cache/com.android.opengl.shaders_cache: Too many open files (24)
12-28 21:50:02.744 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/GraphicBuffer: unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Unknown error -5 (5)
12-28 21:50:02.748 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: 5
12-28 21:50:02.752 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/Parcel: fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC) failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
12-28 21:50:02.752 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
12-28 21:50:02.754 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/Parcel: fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC) failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
12-28 21:50:02.754 27355-27450/co.intellidev.storj E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
```

Comment: provide full recyclerview class.

Comment: The listview actually freezes app when using glide in adapter layouts. Use recyclerview instead.

Comment: @Aks4125 its not a custom recyclerview class

Comment: @RuslanMatveev using reyclerview did not make a difference. Same errror

Comment: The "too many open files" statement ... any chance you could change your IMPL such that the files you open are dramatically reduced?  I work with similar issues in iOS and I typically will open files that correspond to weather or not they're being display (or will be displayed based on the current acceleration/deceleration of a scroll view), but keep everything else closed.  Much more memory-friendly (not to mention drastically faster) in the iOS world ... maybe something similar would be appropriate here.  The cache that's being spooled up seems to have an upper limit, based on those errors.

Comment: @DreamersOrg you are initialising views in your bind holder.. that is the cause for your lag. please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***As Discussed..***

```
public class FilesFragmentCursorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilesFragmentCursorAdapter.FileViewHolder > {
/* objects */
public FilesFragmentCursorAdapter(Activity context, Cursor cursor, Bucket bucket) {
    mContext = context;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    mBucket = bucket;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    downloader = new ThumbnailDownloader(mContext, mBucket);
    manager = GlideApp.with(mContext);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mShowThumbnails = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(Constants.PREFS_SHOW_THUMBNAILS, false);
}


@Override
public FilesFragmentCursorAdapter.FileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_file_item, parent, false);
    return new FileViewHolder(itemView); // <- render view here
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FilesFragmentCursorAdapter.FileViewHolder  holder, final int position) {
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PID));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
    long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SIZE));
    String created = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT));
    String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MIME));


    if (id != null) holder.mId.setText(id);
    if (name != null) holder.mName.setText(name);

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactsList.size();
}

public class FileViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mId;
    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mSize;
    // so on
    public FileViewHolder (View view) {
        super(view);
        mId = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_id);
        mName = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_name);
        mSize = view.findViewById(R.id.list_file_size);
        // so on


    }
}
}
```

Update your adapter class accordingly.

---

I wonder why you are skipping cache for glide and not storing in cache.

```
manager.load(thumbnailPath).skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(holder.image);
```

change to this and allow glide to cache resulting image not the original one.

```
manager.load(thumbnailPath).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).into(holder.image);
```

Comment: thanks this greatly reduced the lag which technically answers this question. Have to open up a new question for the too many files error.

Comment: @DreamersOrg yes.. send me link if possible